# Turn image background into alpha with CSS filters?

Tags: css, css-filters

I have an image that is a simple coloured text on a black background. Is there a CSS filter (or a hacky combination of filters) that would allow me to turn black colour into complete transparency (essentially leaving me with just text)?

Comment: You should use an image editor to modify an image

Comment: WebKit only and deprecated: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/#article-header-id-5

Comment: I have never seen this ability with CSS. You could use JS to manipulate the image with the canvas API. Check out this [tutorial](https://hmp.is.it/creating-chroma-key-effect-html5-canvas/)

Comment: You might want to look into [SVG filter effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html). Not sure if you can achieve the request result with them, though.